# Recursively pass counter variable in Java

Tags: java, recursion, counter

I have a function which calls itself recursively:

```
public int foo(int num, int counter)
{
    if (num > 0)
    {
        counter++;
        num--;
        foo(num, counter);
    }

    return counter;
}
```

From main method I call function with:

```
System.out.println(bst.foo(3, 0));
```

I expect such behavior:

```
public int foo(int num, int counter)
{
    // counter = 0
    // num = 3
    if (num > 0)
    {
        counter++; // counter = 1
        num--; // num = 2
        if (num > 0)
        {
            counter++; // counter = 2
            num--; // num = 1
            if (num > 0)
            {
                counter++; // counter = 3
                num--; // num = 0
                if (num > 0)
                {
                    // don't execute as num = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return counter; // return 3
}
```

But function always returns `1` and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're passing the *value* of `counter`, not the variable itself.  Your recursive call can't modify the value of `counter` in the outer invocation.  Java is pass-by-value.

One possible solution is to do

```
 counter = foo(num, counter);
```

in the recursive call.  Or, alternately, just `return foo(num, counter)`, since you don't do anything with `counter` afterwards except return it.